# onmozfullscreenchange warning in Firefox (not using react)

Tags: javascript, firefox

I keep getting this error in Firefox console.

```
onmozfullscreenchange is deprecated. editresume.js:411:4
onmozfullscreenerror is deprecated. editresume.js:411:4
Ignoring get or set of property that has [LenientThis] because the “this” object is incorrect.
```

If I go to my code file, for that line number, this is what I have

```
tempbutton.setAttributeNode(attid);
```

and, I am not using onmozfullscreenchange or onmozfullscreenerror anywhere.

Why am I getting this? It is also triggers a debugger exception for some reason, at that line number.

Note : I dont get a similar error/warning/breakpoint trigger on Chrome. So, its Firefox only.

Firefox version - 70.0
Chrome version - 77.0.X

Comment: The mozfullscreen messages should just be warning messages (yellow), not errors (red). Are you sure it's what triggers the exception? What version of Firefox? Note that at some point even internal plugins were firing this mozfullscreen messages (like <video> element built-in controls, pdf plugin etc.).

Comment: I have removed all of my custom exceptions prior to posting this question. updated my question with one more error/warning and browser details.

Comment: Could be. now (I did not change that specific line) but those errors in the console are gone but the breakpoint is still triggering :) either way, I will see what others will have to say on this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This message may appear when logging the `window` or `document` objects and extending the resulting message in the Console.

It's because these getters are configured to warn about this deprecation so that developers can update their code accordingly.
However, this deprecation notice doesn't look at **what** tried to get it, so when the Console itself tries to get the value of these properties, it will also trigger the warning notification.

But your debugger exception certainly comes from somewhere else.